# on Android, embedded html5 video tag would stretch the video playback

Tags: android, html, video, aspect-ratio, stretched

I have a video tag with width and height set to a dimension that does not fit the video's aspect ratio. When I see the page on an Android tablet, the video playback is stretched to fill the video 'frame'. Whereas on ipad or desktop browsers it will be centered.

```
<video width="xxx" height="yyy">
   <source ...>
   ...
</video>
```

If I only use width but not height, then the video will maintain its aspect ratio but I want to keep the height and center the video playback.

Is there anyway to accomplish this on Android browsers?

Thanks,